# UNION SELECT mysql php pdo no value return

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
SELECT t1.case_num AS casenum, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
     NULL, NULL
FROM luponcase_tbl t1
WHERE t1.case_num = :id AND t1.status = :active
UNION
SELECT mhearing_number, mhearing_status, mhearing_number, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
    NULL, NULL
FROM luponcase_mediation_tbl t4
WHERE t4.case_num = :id AND t4.status = :active
UNION
SELECT mfileblob, mfile_type, mfilesize, mhearing_number, mnameoffile, NULL, NULL, NULL,
    NULL, NULL
FROM luponcase_mediation_reference_tbl t5
WHERE t5.case_num = :id AND t5.status = :active
```

This is my sql for union and i am not getting result so i tried to echo the result

```
while ($selected_row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                        print_r($selected_row);
}
```

to my surprise the result is

```
Array ( [casenum] => 14 [NULL] => )
```

I am assuming that the first value is ok then the `NULL` columns are not. How to make it in a way that i will get only the columns except the `NULL` ones.

Answer (score 0):

When you connect to the database, you can set some attributes to control how PDO handles Nulls and Empty Strings when they are returned by the database query

Comment: can you share them with me i have no idea on them right now

Comment: mate the problem with me is that the column actually does not exist it was just included so that i can have a UNION. Unlike the sample that the column really exists

Comment: I think you can't ignore null column because you use union and you have to  same number of columns in both tables so  U will get null column

Comment: So let me rephrase the question how can i iterate all the result?i mean i am now stuck in the first null i can live with getting the null as long as i get all the return value of the select

Comment: I think i can't understand your question properly. What Do you want exactly? Do you need null column in resultset or not? If not then Why You are add extra ' Null ' column in select query?

Comment: I dont need the null columns. i added null columns there so that i can do the UNION select because the columns in each table differ.i need to select data from these table and i think the only to do it is by using union select.